# Avoid copying buttons in range

Tags: excel, vba

i have a macro where i copy paste a range, which also has buttons in there.
Now i dont want the buttons to get copied. How can i do that?

I copy the whole table and insert it again at A32.

[image]

```
lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Do While counter = 0
  For i = 32 To lrow
    If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Review Participants" And counter = 1 Then
     lastrev = lrowrev
     lrowrev = i - 1 'row where the second last review starts
     aboveR = lrowrev - lastrev
     Exit For
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Review Participants" And counter <> 1 Then
     counter = counter + 1
     lrowrev = i


     lcol = 11  'hardcode last col ~~ Alt:  'lcol = .Cells(i + 1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last meeting of the review is our reference for lastcol
        ElseIf counter = 1 And i = lrow Then
        lrowrev = i + 2
        aboveR = (i + 2) - 32
        Exit For
End If
Next
Loop

lastcolumn = Split(Cells(, lcol).Address, "$")(1)
Set rngtocopy = .Range("A" & 32 & ":" & lastcolumn & lrowrev)

Debug.Print rngtocopy.Address

'aboveR = .Range("A" & 32 & ":" & lastcolumn & lrowrev - 1).Rows.Count ' amount of rows copied

Set rngins = .Range("A32").EntireRow
Debug.Print rngins.EntireRow.Resize(aboveR + 2).Address


        rngins.EntireRow.Resize(aboveR + 2).Insert xlShiftDown 'insert the amount of rows, we copied
        'Range("A" & lrow).Offset(5).EntireRow.Hidden = False

             Set rngins = .Range("A32")
             Debug.Print rngins.Address
             rngtocopy.Copy
             rngins.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

Comment: The fastest way (anyhow) is to use arrays. But, do you need the copied range format?

Comment: I adapted the code in a way to also allow the range format copying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub copyRangeNoButt()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, arrRng As Variant
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set rng = sh.Range("D2:E10"): rng.Copy
   arrRng = rng.value
   With sh.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(arrRng, 1), UBound(arrRng, 2))
        .value = arrRng
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats'comment this line if format is not needed. It takes much more time than all the rest of the code, in case of a big range...
   End With
End Sub
```

Of course, you must adapt the code to use your range to be copied definition and the cell where to be pasted (even if in another worksheet).

Answer (score 0):

> Now i dont want the buttons to get copied. How can i do that?

You can also use [PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial). You can take advantage of [XlPasteType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) to copy and paste only relevant part. For example, here is a one liner in case you want to paste

**A**. Everything **except** the image

```
rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
```

**B**. **Only** Values

```
rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

**In action**

[image]

Comment: this somehow doesnt help. buttons still get copied. please check my question. i will edit.

Comment: You are using `PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll`. I never suggested that. I suggested  `Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`

Comment: It works. I updated the post with a screenshot. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: this isnt exactly how my code works, maybe thats why. My code pushes the copied range down and insert at the place of the old range.

Comment: When you insert (not copy) the range down, do the button also move down or remain at the same location?

Comment: they remain at the same spot

Comment: Exactly. So the buttons are not pasted because of my code. They were there before hand :)

Comment: Forget the code for a moment. Now explain in simple steps what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: okay these are the steps of my code :
1) Copy range (A32:Kx)
2) Paste amount of copied rows, at A32
3) paste copied range to A32

Comment: Sorry that is confusing... After you copy `A32:Kx` why paste it at A32 twice?

Comment: I kind of make a list, where the "old" table, is being pushed down in the worksheet (thats why i insert rows) and then is again pasted at the same spot, so you can update it. You understand my friend?

Comment: Yup That is much better explanation :)  Now a quick question. `Set rngtocopy = .Range("A" & 32 & ":" & lastcolumn & lrowrev)` You set your range here and then when you insert (push) the table down there is only blank cells where the old table was so why are you copying `rngtocopy.Copy` because it will still refer to old range and not the range which was shifted down.

Comment: erm thats a good point...dont know why i did it like that. what should i change?

Comment: Lets not do anything here. @FaneDuru has already answered your main query. If you change the question then it will be unfair to him. I would recommend posting a new question with your code. Asking on how to improve the code. This way if I or anyone else is free can take a shot at it :) Also remember that `Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` will not copy the shapes across ;)